# What is the correct way to make changes to Userena Templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

I located the Userena templates in my site-packages/userena.  I was told by someone that I should not be editing any of the files in this directory but instead I should make new templates.

I'm guessing that I should be making new files that inherit from the parents files in the site-packages/userena folder?  If this is true, I understand how to do this using Python and inheritance, but how do I do this with templates?

Do I just make a new template in my project/templates folder and add a line at the top to inherit from site-packages/userena/templates?

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Userena github](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena) and find the templates. You can override them by putting the templates under templates/userena/ (copy their templates folder and use it in your project)